# Find equation of projection and symmetry

Tags: geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the euclidean canonical structure and the plane $\pi:x-2y+2z=1$ and the line $d:(x,y,z)=(t+1,1,2-t), t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Find:

$i) S_\pi (d)$, where $S_\pi (d)$ is the orthogonal symmetry relative to the plane $\pi$

$ii) S_d (\pi)$, where $S_d (\pi)$ is the orthogonal symmetry relative to the line $d$

**My Attempt**

$i)$

In order to solve $i)$ i thought that the orthogonal projection of the line $d$ onto the plane $\pi$, $pr_\pi (d)$, would be helpful:

Take a point $P=(t+1,1,2-t)\in d$,  $t\in\mathbb{R}$

$P_0=\pi$ $\cap$ $(P+dir(\pi)^\perp)$ is the orthogonal projection of $P$ on $\pi$ and $P+dir(\pi)^\perp$ is the linear affine variety through P whose direction is $dir(\pi)^\perp$

So, $d_1=$ $ P+dir(\pi)^\perp$: $ \frac{x-t-1}{1}=\frac{y-1}{-2}=\frac{z-2+t}{2}=s, $ $s\in\mathbb{R}$

Now, we need $d_1\cap \pi: (s+t+1)-2(1-2s)+2(2s-t+2)=1$ so
$s=\frac{t-2}{9}$ and $d_1\cap \pi=(\frac{10t+7}{9},\frac{-2t+13}{9},\frac{-7t+14}{9})$

So now, this means that the parametric equation of
$pr_\pi (d)$ is $(\frac{10t+7}{9},\frac{-2t+13}{9},\frac{-7t+14}{9})?$

If that is so, the equation for
$S_\pi (d)$ is  $2pr_\pi (d)-id$?

At $ii)$ how could I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $(i)$, you want to reflect line $d$ relative to plane $\pi$, and for that you can use the reflection formula that relates a point $\mathbf{p}$ to its reflection $\mathbf{p'}$:

$ \mathbf{p'} = \mathbf{r_0} + F ( \mathbf{p} - \mathbf{r_0} ) $

where $\mathbf{r_0}$ is any point on the plane, and the reflection matrix is given by

$ F = I - 2 \dfrac{ {\mathbf{n n}}^T}{\mathbf{n}^T \mathbf{n}} $

We have $\mathbf{n} = \langle 1, -2, 2 \rangle $, hence

$ F = I - \dfrac{2}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && - 2 && 2 \\ -2 && 4 && -4 \\ 2 && -4 && 4 \end{bmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 4 && -4 \\ 4 && -5 && 8 \\ -4 && 8 && -5 \end{bmatrix} $

We can take $\mathbf{r_0} = \langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle $

Now the equation of the line $d$ is $\mathbf{p} = \langle t+1, 1 , 2 - t \rangle $

Therefore,

$ \mathbf{p'} = \langle 1, 0, 0 \rangle + \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 4 && -4 \\ 4 && -5 && 8 \\ -4 && 8 && -5 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} t \\ 1\\ 2-t \end{bmatrix} =\dfrac{1}{3} \langle   5t - 1  ,   -4 t + 11  ,  t  - 2 \rangle $

At $t = 5$

$ \mathbf{p'} = \langle 8 , -3 , 1 \rangle $

Hence the line $\mathbf{p'}$ can be described by

$ \mathbf{p'} = \langle 8 , -3, 1 \rangle + t \langle 5 , - 4 , 1 \rangle $

Now, for $(ii)$ you want to reflect the plane $\pi$ relative to the line $d$

This is equivalent to rotating plane $\pi$ by $180^\circ$ about line $d$

The rotation matrix is (using the Rodrigues' rotation matrix formula with $\theta = 180^\circ$ )

$ R = \mathbf{a a}^T + (I - \mathbf{a a}^T) (-1) = 2 \mathbf{a a}^T - I $

where $\mathbf{a}$ is the unit vector along line $d$; i.e. $\mathbf{a} = (\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) $.  This gives us

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && -1 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ -1 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Now the equation of plane $\pi$ is

$ \mathbf{n}^T (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r_0} ) = 0 \hspace{40pt} (1a) $

The reflection of a point $\mathbf{r} $ is

$ \mathbf{r'} = \mathbf{d_0} + R ( \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{d_0} ) \hspace{40pt}(1b) $

Where $\mathbf{d_0}$ is any point on line $d$, and we can take it as $\langle 1,1,2 \rangle $.  Noting that $R^{-1} = R^T = R $, then we can write

$ \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{d_0} + R ( \mathbf{r'} - \mathbf{d_0} ) \hspace{40pt}(1c) $

Substituting $(1c)$ into $(1a)$ gives us

$ \mathbf{n}^T ( R ( \mathbf{r'} - \mathbf{d_0} ) + \mathbf{d_0} - \mathbf{r_0} ) = 0 \hspace{40pt} (1a) $

Substituting the numerical values for $\mathbf{n} = [1, -2, 2]^T , \mathbf{d_0} = [1, 1, 2]^T ,  R \mathbf{d_0} = [-2, -1, -1]^T , \mathbf{r_0} = [1, 0, 0]^T$ , and $ R^T \mathbf{n} = R \mathbf{n} = [-2, 2, -1]$, then the equation of the reflected plane $\pi'$ is

$ \langle -2, 2, -1 \rangle \cdot \big( \mathbf{r} - \langle 2, 2, 3 \rangle \big) = 0 $